# GAE Search: Atom Fields with Quotes

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I'm getting started with Google App Engine, and I'm using the Search API.  Can I construct a search query against an `Atom` field if that field has quotation marks in it?  I don't see a way to escape quote characters in the [query documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings).

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need to escape anything? Why not just send the literal value? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can escape quotation marks by preceding them with a backslash.  Note that in this case the entire value should also be enclosed in quotation marks, as mentioned in [this section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Queries_on_atom_fields).

But an atom field with an embedded quotation mark seems rather weird.  Why would you want to do such a thing?